# MS VC++ Convert a byte array to a BSTR?

Tags: c++, arrays, bstr

I have a string that starts out in a .Net application, is encrypted and stored in AD. It's then picked up by a native C++ app and decrypted to produce an array of bytes
e.g "ABCDEF" becomes 00,41,00,42,00,43,00,44,00,45 once it has been decrypted at the C++ end.

I need to take this byte array and convert it to the BSTR "ABCDEF" so that I can use it elsewhere and I can't find a way to acomplish this last step.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have an array of arbitrary bytes, use [`SysAllocStringByteLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221637.aspx). But it looks like, despite being in a byte array, your data is really a UTF-16-encoded Unicode string, so in that case, you're probably better off using [`SysAllocStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221639.aspx) instead. Pass the byte-array pointer to the function (type-cast to `OLECHAR*`), and the characters will be copied into the new string for you, along with an additional null character at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'd already been down this road and what ends up in the BSTR is not a valid unicode string.
Whan I print the BSTR to the console I get a bunch of ?s (oddly except for a space character that comes out correctly), the right number of ?s but not the correct characters.
On the assumption that I've screwed up the console output I tested the BSTR against what shoud be in there and the tests fail. 
I'm using BSTR newStr = SysAllocStringLen((OLECHAR *)decryptedBytes, dataLength/2); to create the string. The decryptedBytes array does contain a valid byte stream 00,41... etc.

Comment: That may be an endianness problem - bytes within every Unicode char are swapped and you need to swap them back.

Answer (score 0):

The "decrypted string" is just a Unicode string - latin characters contain the first byte equal to null when represented in Unicode. So you don't need any real conversion, just cook a BSTR out of that buffer.

Knowing the number of Unicode characters - it will be half the length of the buffer - call `SysAllocStringLen()` to allocate a long enough null-terminated uninitialized BSTR. Then copy your array onto the allocated string with `memcpy()`. Alternatively you can call `SysAllocStringLen()` and pass it the byte buffer so that it does the copy for you and skip the `memcpy()`. Don't forget to call `SysFreeString()` when you no longer need the BSTR.

Comment: Why create an uninitialized string and then copy the characters afterward? `SysAllocStringLen` will copy the characters for you if you let it.

Comment: I think the presumption is that the characters are in some storage which can be streamed; in this case we can avoid allocation for the source buffer by streaming them directly into the BSTR. In practice, this likely doesn't matter in this particular case.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Yes, quite a reasonable ammendment.